# primefaces header panelgrid left position

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know how I put the title or header of an p:panelgrid towards to side left, so text-align: left, for default the position is center. My code is the following :

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="colC1,colC2" styleClass="noBorders" style="width: 100%;" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Information General"/>
        </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
```

CSS

```
.noBorders tr, .noBorders td {
border: none !important;
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.leftAlign {
      float: left;
}
```

JSF:

```
<h:outputText value="Information General" styleClass="leftAlign"/>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not very helpful. Please explain what you are doing and why.

Comment: I do not exactly know what is here to explain more. `<h:outputText />` generates HTML `<span>` element that if you want to align to the left you need to use CSS properly